# Multiple annotations found at this line: first program Android Programming_ The Big Nerd Ranch Guide f

Tags: android, android-layout

I copied the first program from Android Programming_ The Big Nerd Ranch Guide book. and i  am getting the following error.
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element
    - The markup in the document following the root element must be well-
     formed.
on line no 16.
here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".QuizActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    andriod:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/true_button" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/false_button"   />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use two parents layout in the same xml. This is not possible in Android. Use either `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` as a parent in this case.

Use this template:

```
<RelativeLayout
    //relative layout attributes
    >
    //you can add as many as elements here

    <LinearLayout
        //linear layout attributes
        >
        //you can add as many as elements here
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want to use `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` together, Add a separate parent Layout in xml file, like this:

```
<RalativeLayout
    //this is your main parent layout
    >

    //Add as many as Linear/Relative layout here doesn't matter.

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout: you are trying to init two seperate layout for one xml file. Use one main layout & u can use other layout as its child.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".QuizActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />



<LinearLayout 

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 //u can specify `below` , `above` property as per your need
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:text="@string/question_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    andriod:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/true_button" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/false_button"   />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thank you. In book it is written in the same way as i posted. so why it was showing me error? is there any mistake in the book?

Comment: check twice in book. it may be two different layout. nd may be u wrote it as whole one layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".QuizActivity"  >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="@string/question_text" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/true_button" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/false_button"   />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```